# Search which man sections contain a given entry

Tags: linux, man

On Linux (or any other OS that uses the `man` tool), there are typically several sections of the manual. Often, a given entry (such as `echo` or `printf`) exists in multiple sections, but not all of them. Is there a simple way to check which sections of the manual that entry can be found in?

Obviously, one can try `man [section] [entry]` and just run through every section in the manual, but honestly, I'm not even sure what the complete list of sections is (or how to find that definitively), and I'm looking for something a little less brute-force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `whatis` (eg, `whatis printf`).  The sections of man are not random.  See [Wikipedia: Man page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page).  For example, section 2 contains only System calls while section 3 only contains C Library calls. There is a version of `printf` for use on the command line so it is located in section 1. But there is also one in the C Library so that is located in section 3.

You will have to create the `whatis` database first with `makewhatis -w` (on Cygwin, it is in /usr/sbin).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Unfortunately, `whatis` returns either `nothing appropriate` or `manpath is null` (despite that it isn't) on the systems I'm using right now. And I've read that Wikipedia page before, but as it makes clear, different systems have different sections, and I'm not sure how to check which ones are present except by brute force.

Comment: @patrickvacek, have to create the whatis database first with `makewhatis -w` (on Cygwin, it is in /usr/sbin).

Comment: Oops, now it makes so much more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

These work with FreeBSD `man`, with the `man` from Linux distributions and the likes of Debian Hurd, and even with Cygwin `man`:

```
man -a -f ${entry}
```

or, more cryptically but perhaps more usefully in shell scripts,

```
man -a -w ${entry}
```

Of course, you must have your `whatis` database populated correctly.  With Cygwin, this doesn't happen out of the box, unlike with FreeBSD, Debian, and the like.  One has to run `makewhatis`.

Comment: The latter (`man -a -w`) works beautifully for me with cygwin, but I'm still having trouble with my Linux systems... although I think that may be specific to those systems. But even on cygwin, the former (`man -a -f`) yields `nothing appropriate` (its own words).

Comment: You didn't ask about Cygwin, and I didn't answer about Cygwin.  Cygwin's `man` is a different beast.  If you want Cygwin answers, it's best not to start a question with "On Linux" and tag it as [Linux].

Comment: Sorry for any confusion; I only mentioned Cygwin because I turned to it after my lack of success with Linux (CentOS) systems. My question remains focused on Linux. I just tried the commands on an Ubuntu system and they worked beautifully. (And after creating the whatis database in Cygwin, even the `man -a -f` works, too.) Thanks!